# Incrementing values in array backwards

Tags: c, algorithm, math

I want go through all combinations of values in array by incrementing it backwards.
So let's have an array

```
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

I want to increment it this way: {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1} > {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2}...{p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1,p-1}.

For examples smaller array, p=3 : {0,0,0}>{0,0,1}>{0,0,2}>{0,1,0}>{0,1,1}>{0,1,2}...{2,2,2}

Array can be `sizeof(int)*m` big, where 1<=m<=10.

Can someone help me out with algorithm for that?

EDIT: Sorry, forgot about this.. 
Ok sorry for confusion but I have one more condition..

That array won't be in that form. It will be something like this **example**

```
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int help[10] = {3,4,0,1,0,0,3,0,1,0};
```

and i want to get combination of values in array[help[]!=0], in this case
array[0],array[1],array[3],array[6],array[8] so ->

```
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0};
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0};
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0};
    int array[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0};
    int array[10] = {2,2,0,2,0,0,2,0,2,0};
```

p=3 
Something like that for() cycle will go i=0,1,3,6,8, where the values are i=help[i]!=0.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, so you're representing numbers in base 4?

Comment: Essentially representing the number in base(p) + 1. You need to show an attempt at your algorithm before asking for help.

Comment: yes, it should've been in base(p) but made a mistake there:) gonna correct it

Comment: If you know how to add 1 to a multi-digit number, you already know how to do this.

Comment: It's not necessary to set each value to 0 by the way, you can just use `= {0};` to set them all.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, had to edit the question :/. its very similar just changing values of speficic array[index].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
void increment(int array[], size_t size, int limit)
{
     do
     {
         if (++array[--size] != limit)
         {
             break;
         }
         array[size] = 0; // value overflow
     }
     while (size);
}
```

Usage:

```
int array[10];
memset(array, 0, sizeof(array));

increment(array, 10, 3);
```

Edit: algorithm with filter

```
void increment(int array[], int filter[], size_t size, int limit)
{
     do
     {
         if (!filter[--size])
         {
             // skip this position
             continue;
         }
         if (++array[size] != limit)
         {
             break;
         }
         array[size] = 0; // value overflow
     }
     while (size);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, its helpful, but I had to edit the question, really appriciate your answer!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `if (++array[--size] != limit)` instead of `if (++array[size] != limit)` ?

Comment: @user2199158 I use C indexes in the algorithm, which are 0-based. So the first statement in the loop makes index correct. I.e. if array size is 10, indexes are [0..9]. If you have different indexing scheme, adapt as needed. Just make sure the index value is correct before the first use.

Comment: yea i know but isn't it testing `if (++array[10]!= limit)` ?

Comment: Oh you decremented it in if (!filter[--size]) ... sorry:)

Answer (score 1):

I see that the question has changed a bit, from incrementing an array backwards to adding one to a base(n) number... that's a different problem.

```
int base = 3;

for( int i = (sizeof( array ) / sizeof( array[0] ))-1; i >= 0; )
{
    if( ++array[i] < base )
        break;
    else
        array[i--] = 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to assume that the array does not contain pre-initialized values, yes.

Comment: If the array is pre-initialized, you would be overwriting the value if the array[i-1] element with 0 explicitly. On the other hand, if you're adding 1 to a number that already has a value, you would "break" the initial value by assigning 0 to it.

Answer (score 0):

this is equivalent to simply incrementing through the natural numbers, from 0 to (p+1) ^ arrayLength, in base p+1.

so for your example,

```
for (long i=0; i<4^10; i++)
{
   convert i to string in base (p+1), left- padding with 0s
   convert characters in string to comma separated array format and print 
}
```